# APScheduler how to trigger job now

Tags: python, apscheduler

I have an APScheduler in a Flask app, sending events at some intervals.

Now i need to "refresh" all jobs, in fact just starting them *now* if they don't run without touching on the defined interval.

I'v tried to call job.pause() then job.resume() and nothing, and using job. reschedule_job(...) would trigger it but also change the interval... which i don't want.

My actual code is bellow:

```
cron = GeventScheduler(daemon=True)
# Explicitly kick off the background thread
cron.start()

cron.add_job(_job_time, 'interval', seconds=5, id='_job_time')
cron.add_job(_job_forecast, 'interval', hours=1, id='_job_forecast_01')

@app.route("/refresh")
def refresh():
    refreshed = []
    for job in cron.get_jobs():
         job.pause()
         job.resume()
         refreshed.append(job.id)
    return json.dumps( {'number': len(cron.get_jobs()), 'list': refreshed} )
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You could just run the job function directly too.

```
for job in cron.get_jobs():
    job.func()
```

If you had args or kwargs being passed into the function, you'd have to pull those out of `job.args` and/or `job.kwargs`. See [apscheduler.job.Job](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/job.html#module-apscheduler.job)

Answer (score 44):

I discourage from calling `job.func()` as proposed in the accepted answer. The scheduler wouldn't be made aware of the fact that job is running and will mess up with the regular scheduling logic.

Instead use the job's [`modify()`](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html#modifying-jobs) function to set its `next_run_time` property to `now()`:

```
for job in scheduler.get_jobs():
    job.modify(next_run_time=datetime.now())
```

[Also refer to the actual implementation of class `Job`](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/blob/v3.7.0/apscheduler/job.py).

Comment: Do you know if changing next_run_time will interfere with the schedule? E.g. if the interval is x will the next run become x in the future from next_run_time when I modify it?

Comment: If I understand your question and APScheduler correctly, then the job should run _at the point in time_ which you specify with `next_run_time` (and not a predefined run interval after that point in time)

Comment: Not quite my question. I have jobs I added with a set interval, and I am wondering if the previously planned next run (set by the interval) will be at all affected by modifying the next run time. I assume it will just mean the job won't run again until after `interval` has passed again?

Comment: Skimming over APScheduler's source code quickly, it indeed seems to work the way you describe it (scheduler will wait another interval after the manually triggered run). That's a transparent, straight forward approach.

Comment: if the job is pause, this method will run the job immediately but change its status from pause to active.

Comment: @ming then we could just test whether the job is paused and then skip it, couldn’t we?

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround i've done using the following.
In summary i cycle through all jobs `cron.get_jobs()` and create a one-time job using Job object to a 'date' trigger, which only trigger once, at `datetime.now` since not specified.

```
def refresh():
    refreshed = []
    for job in cron.get_jobs():
        cron.add_job(job.func, 'date', id='{0}.uniq'.format(job.id), max_instances=1)
        refreshed.append(job.id)
    return json.dumps( {'number': len(cron.get_jobs()), 'list': refreshed} )
```

Comment: Also already 2 years ago, I've posted a new answer that will make user of the proper scheduling mechanisms to start a job _now_.

Answer (score 1):

Very late answer, but I think that what you need is to simply call the methods in your "refresh" route.