# Can we force run the jobs in APScheduler job store?

Tags: python, apscheduler

Using APScheduler version 3.0.3. Services in my application internally use APScheduler to schedule & run jobs. Also I did create a wrapper class around the actual APScheduler(just a façade, helps in unit tests). For unit testing these services, I can mock the this wrapper class. But I have a situation where I would really like the APScheduler to run the job (during test). Is there any way by which one can force run the job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no default trigger to launch a job immediately, to achieve this 
you can get the current time and set a DateTrigger to the job like this:

```
my_job.modify_job(trigger=DateTrigger(run_date=datetime.datetime.now()))
```

this way you will "force" the job to run, but you have to make sure to insert the job again in the scheduler, another option is just creating a new job to run the same function with the add_job function

```
sched.add_job(func=your_function(),
              trigger=DateTrigger(run_date=datetime.datetime.now()))
```

this way you don't have to do any additional step.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: you can write logic of your job in separate function. So, you will be able to call this function in your scheduled job as well as somewhere else. I guess that this is a more explicit way to do what you want.

Comment: This has the disadvantage of allowing a concurrent run of your code in case the scheduler happens to "wake up" when you are calling your function manually.

Answer (score 0):

Two alternatives.

1. change the jobs next_run_time(not verified personally, but here says it works: [APScheduler how to trigger job now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230896/apscheduler-how-to-trigger-job-now))

   job = self.scheduler.get_job(job_id=job_id)
   job.modify(next_run_time=datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=5))
2. Add a run-once job to trigger it(verified):

   self.scheduler.add_job(func=job.run,
   executor=executor,
   trigger="date",
   max_instances=1,
   run_date=datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=5))