# APScheduler using cron and instant triggers together

Tags: python, apscheduler

Im writing an app for Raspberry Pi. App has to run periodic tasks and also connected to main server over socket.io to get commands from server. I preferred APscheduler to run periodic tasks because it gives ability to control task intervals dynamically. I used socketIO_client to get cron statements from server and apply them on running tasks. Up until this point it works like charm. Yet i need some more functionality.

Between periodic task runs, i want to run tasks by socket.io server events. On this site i found similar problem on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230896/apscheduler-how-to-trigger-job-now) question and applied answer. Normally APscheduler is smart enough not to run task before previous task finished by setting coalesce True and/or max_instances 1. But with job.func() method, job starts even though previous hasn't finished yet.

Basically what i want is run a function periodically and also be able to run between intervals by server events. If job started either cron or server event, up until it finishes new job should be passed. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, that is not currently possible natively with APScheduler. You'll have to create two jobs and share a lock object or something among them that will make sure they don't run simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks for the answer